# displaying a single row in view of codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, templates

I am new in codeigniter and I am using version 2.1.3_2

I want to send a single row from model to controller then from controller to view. I checked some of the same kind of question discussed earlier here but couldn't fix it

code for my controller is

```
   public function updateq()
{
    $qid1=$this->input->get('qid',true);
    $showd['data1']=$this->quiz_model->updateq($qid1);
    $this->load->view('Quiz/update',$showd);
}
```

code for model is

```
    public function updateq($qid1)
{
    $this->db->where('qid',$qid1);
    $up=$this->db->get('question');
    return $up->row();
}
```

Now the code for view is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php echo form_open('quiz/update');
    ?>

    <table width="77%" height="327" align="center" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td height="39" colspan="2" align="center">
    <h2> update your Question Here</h2>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="97">Question</td>
    <td width="287"><textarea name="question" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="2" required="required" value="<?php echo $data1->question;?> "></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Option 1 :</td>
    <td><textarea name="option1" id="textarea3" cols="45" rows="2" required="required" value="<?php echo $data1->option1 ;?> "></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Option 2 :</td>
    <td><textarea name="option2" id="textarea4" cols="45" rows="2" required="required"value="<?php echo $data1->option2;?> "></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Option 3: </td>
    <td><textarea name="option3" id="textarea5" cols="45" rows="2" required="required"value="<?php echo $data1->option3;?> "></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Option 4:</td>
 <td><textarea name="option4" id="textarea6" cols="45" rows="2" required="required"value="<?php echo $data1->option4;?> "></textarea></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
  <label for="select2">Correct Answer</label></td>
 <td><select name="ra" id="select2">
  <option value="Select Correct option">Select Correct option</option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button1" id="button2" value="Submit Question &ans;  Answer" /></td>
 </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have checked that the query is returning a row. but I can't understand why I am getting blank text boxes in my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<textarea name="option1" id="textarea3" cols="45" rows="2" required="required"><?php echo $data1->option1 ;?></textarea>
```

Paste `php` code inside `textarea` instead using `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and this is how I solved it.
In your view you can have something like this:

```
  $value = $data1['fieldname'];

<tr>
     <td colspan="2">
         <input type="text" name="value2" id="value2" value='<?php echo $value ?>' />
     </td>
</tr>
```

am sure this should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks joni for the correction am a newbie in codeigniter i will make corrections.